# Find a function which grows slower (but not by a polynomial factor slower) than $n^{\log_27}$

Tags: functions, algorithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity

So if I divide $f(n) = n^{\log_27}$ by $log_27$, it should be growing slower 
than $f(n)$ (and still not by a polynomial factor).

$g(n) = f(n)/\log_27$

Is my assumption true? If not what should I do instead?

Comment: A constant factor (here $\log_27$) is always absorbed into the big Oh, and does not really matter much. I would guess that a logarithmic factor is intended.

Comment: What if  $g(n) = n^{\log_26}$ , then it would be in big O and also grow slower than $f(n)$ without a polynomial factor.

Comment: That doesn't work. The ratio would be $n^{\log_2(7/6)}$ which is a polynomial factor. Try $g(n)=f(n)/\log_2n$.

Comment: ah!! I understood! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If the function $f(n)=n^{\log_2 7}$ grows faster than $n^2$ but slower than $x^3$. Let $g(n)=f(n)~p(n)$ it will grow slower than $f(n)$
for non-polynomial functions(factors) such as $p(n)=\frac{1}{1+n^k}. k>0.$ Let $k$ be non-integral: $k=0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 5/7, 7/5.$

Comment: isnt $\frac{1}{n^k}$ the same as  $n^{-k}$? Wouldnt that mean that $g(n)=f(n)~p(n)$ is also $g(n) = n^{\log_2 7 -k}$ and that would be a polynomial factor.

Comment: Oh! no please note that $k$ can also be 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0,7,.3/2, 5/7,...(non-integral).

Comment: For the purposes of computational complexity **any** power function $n^\alpha, \alpha\in\Bbb{R}_{>0}$, is viewed as a polynomial (even though in algebra polynomials only have terms with non-negative integers as exponents).

Answer (score 0):

1. It depends on what is meant by "grows more slowly".
2. Since $n^{-k}\ln n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ for any fixed $k>0,$ you can let $g(n)=f(n)/\ln n$ for $n>1.$ Then $g(n)\to \infty$ and $g(n)/f(n)\to 0,$ but $[g(n)/f(n)]\cdot n^k\to \infty$ for any constant $k>0.$
3. Instead, for non-negative integer $m$ and for $10^m\le n<10^{m+1}$ let $g(n)=f(n)/(m+1) .$